# Check to see if SQLite database connection is still open

Tags: iphone, sqlite

how can you check to see if a database is still open?

I am using this to open it:

```
   if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database1) == SQLITE_OK) {
}
```

I assume it would be something like the following, but when I think the database is open it shows as closed:  (Am I on the right track or completely wrong here?) :

```
if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database1)){

    NSLog(@"DATABASE OPEN?");

}else{

    NSLog(@"DATABASE CLOSED?");


}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
      if(sqlite3_open([temppath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
      {
      NSLog(@"DATABASE OPEN?");
      sqlite3_close(database);
      }
      else
      {
         NSLog(@"DATABASE CLOSED?");
      }
```

Comment: Won't that open a new connection to the database? I want to simply check whether the previously opened one has been successfully closed? Thanks very much